# Sorting the np array by second value

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, sorting

If I want to sort this array which is declared by
`np.zeros((50),dtype=object)` and I want to sort this array by first value,

`[list([2, 5]) list([3, 0]) list([2, 7]) list([3, 1]) list([11, 2])]`

like

`[list([2, 5]) list([2, 7]) list([3, 0]) list([3, 1]) list([11, 2])]`

What should I use?
I've been try `sort()`, `sorted()` etc..

Comment: Your question is a duplicate - also, because `[2, 5]` is a string literal, the `list()` in `list([2, 5])` is redundant.

Comment: Just checking.  Is your input supposed to be a 5x2 numpy array?  A list of 5 2-element number arrays?  It's kind of unclear.

Comment: Please, remove salutations. [Should 'Hi', 'thanks', taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)

Comment: Are all lists in your array of same length (here two)?

Comment: @Grismar Ok, I'll do some research. This is my code, `ary[i] = [min(t4), np.argmin(t4)]`, so the `dtype` of array is object, that caused the `list()` type in array.

Comment: @FrankYellin The origin array is a 2D array, but I want to add two integer into this array.

Comment: @maciejwww Already correct it .

Comment: @Ehsan Yes, all the length of list is two.

Comment: @LinChengHan Please see if the posted solution resolves the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if all lists in your array are of the same length, you can use numpy lexsort (`a` is your array):

```
a = np.array(a)
a[np.lexsort((a[:,-1],a[:,-2]))]
#[[ 2  5]
# [ 2  7]
# [ 3  0]
# [ 3  1]
# [11  2]]
```

or equivalently:

```
a[np.lexsort(a.T[::-1,:])]
```

Comment: Already solved!